# How can a C programm recognize that an input integer is too big?

Tags: c, largenumber

Obviously the code below is too naive. How can an very large input be successfully compared with the largest int possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main ( void ) 
{
    unsigned long long input;
    
    printf("Enter a big integer: ");
    scanf ( "%llu", & input) ;
    
    if ( input > ULLONG_MAX ) printf ( " Too big!\n" ) ;
    else printf ( "%llu is not that big.\n" , input ) ; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read it into a string, then try to convert it to an integer with `sscanf()`.

Comment: How would you, as a human, recognize that a number is bigger than 100 if you could only handle numbers from 1-100 and I gave you the digits `283746`?

Comment: To build off of @Barmar's answer, while it's not explicitly _performant_, you could then compare the string form of the converted number to the original input.

Comment: @Barmar No. *scanf functions are not suitable for this task. They don't detect overflows or wraparounds.

Comment: Use one of the strtol, strtoll, strtoul, strtoull.